# Personal Archive not Visible in Outlook

Tags: exchange-2010, archive, outlook-2010

I just added a second user to my Exchange 2010 box, it is in coexistence with exc2003. My account is already set up and working with a personal archive folder.

The user I just set up however is unable to see the archive in Outlook. It is visible in OWA but not outlook. I have created a test profile on my PC with the users account and still no archive, if I jump back to my profile on the same box the archive is there so I know it is not an office versions issue.

UPDATE:

I have deleted all profiles from Outlook (one of which worked with the archive) now any new profiles including my own no longer show up. I think I have broken something In exchange. I get an auto discover certificate error which I am in the process of fixing. Perhaps the 2 problems are related. Also OWA on this server runs on a custom SSL port.

Answer (score 0):

I would try recreating the account after checking the settings in Exchange. [See this link to double check the Exchange settings](http://www.howexchangeworks.com/2009/08/archive-mailbox-in-exchange-2010.html). Also try it with out Exchange Cache Mode. I've always disable that when troubleshooting issues.

Comment: I have just added a new user as a test and it is exactly the same. All the settings seem to be fine. I have compared to the account that works. All Archives are visible in OWA. This seems unnecessarily frustrating.

Comment: Did you try disabling Exchange Cache Mode and/or recreating the profile?

Comment: Yeah, tried with and without cache mode. Made a new profile, also made a brand new test user.

Answer (score 0):

It was the Auto discover service. It was not working correctly since I had 2 HTTPS bindings in the IIS config. The seems somewhat limiting though.. I can add a new binding for as many protocols as I want, but really IIS doesn't want me to do this more than once per protocol, so why let me add the bindings? It seems to me that accessing a web service on a couple of ports would be a fairly common practice...